# Self-Hosted alternative to Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, self-hosted

Is there any hosted, browser-based software - preferably running on PHP, but I'm ready to consider other possibilities as well - that comes close to the experience of using Google Docs? I'm interested mainly in the method of organizing documents, and the minimalistic User Interface - I could live with support for a smaller number of file types.

Both Open Source and Pay software are an option.

(Sorry, I initially put this as "hosted" which I realized later is a mistake. I'm looking for a solution that I can run myself on a server.)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [FengOffice](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/), however, I don't think it has the ability to upload/download as office formats.

There is [EtherPad](http://etherpad.org/), which google docs docs is based off of, but it only has word documents, and I don't think it has upload/download either.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting pointers! I will be looking into EtherPad.

Comment: It is important to note that only the Community Edition of Feng Office is open-source, self-hosted, free-to-use. See http://www.fengoffice.com/web/opensource/ and http://www.fengoffice.com/web/professional_vs_community.php

Comment: For Word documents (eg not Excel), there is also https://nativedocuments.com/ which is a new commercial solution, focused on fidelity, performance and ease of integation.  Disclosure: I have an interest here..

Answer (score 5):

Actually I myself have written something in the vein of google docs. It's backed by a mongoDb database. And I am willing to publish the source code of the project or send it to interested people. So hosting this on your own server would be no problem at all.

You can find the application here: http://mgdx.net/

This was written completely in PHP.

Currently only Rich-Text documents are supported. As in no spreadsheet or other documents.
Features:

- User management
- Pages protected by username
- Simple Rich-Text editing
- Keyboard Shortcuts for editing & saving
- Nested documents
- Optional listing of recent documents
- PDF Export / Download
- Responsive Design (works on mobile Devices)

For SpreadSheets I just found this: http://www.gelsheet.org/

It is stand-alone version of the FengOffice SpreadSheet module.

Comment: http://mgdx.net is the site of some german music band.

Comment: It is not. I don't understand that downvote.

Comment: Weird. Now I can open it. Unfortunately I can't revert my downvote unless the answer is edited, sorry.

Comment: Hmm, I changed the URL in my previous post slightly, but that shouldn't have made a difference. Whatever.. It now points to the correct website.

Comment: How do you do PDF generation?

Comment: I used something like http://mpdf.bpm1.com/. Generates PDF Files from HTML..

Answer (score 1):

MindTouch Platform and MindTouch Core are both self-hosted. The UI is non-invasive and very clean. You can use MindTouch Platform in conjunction with the desktop connecter to import your docs. More steps than viewing a document in Google Docs, but does give you the security of your fire wall. And the WYSIWYG editor makes editing documents as simple as Word.

[As a css junkie and a page linking maverick, I would much rather stay out of Office products and use a solution like MindTouch.] You can still "Paste from Word" in the free edition if you don't want to pay for Platform. You can start with a [free trial of MindTouch Platform](http://www.mindtouch.com/product/) and downgrade to Core if you don't need the extra bells. Though I must say, I do love the extra bells myself!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Atlassian's Confluence is worth your consideration. You can easily create something similar to Google Docs and add far more functionality out of the box.

http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview

Comment: can it also do web-edit of xls files?